# Is there any personal data saved inside a Blender file?

Tags: blend-files

If I upload a file with an HDRI-map, will the others see it? And will the name of the folder in which it lies be visible in the file? Will my computer name be visible? In general, what are the pitfalls about personal data when uploading blender files?

Comment: By card you mean image?

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz yes, I used google translate. HDRI-map of course

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. The path to the image will be visible even if packed. However if you used a subdirectory of the path of the `.blend` e.g. `//Textures/` (`//` means dir of the `.blend`) only this will be visible, including the name of the image. The only way Blender uses absolute paths (to my knowledge) is when you import the image before saving the file, or if you told it that in the global settings.
2. Computer name etc. will not be visible, there is no username, registration or anything else. The version you used to last edit the file can be determined, eg. 2.83.
3. I am not aware of any (other) pitfalls.

Comment: If some file is on a network, the path to it might include the name or local IP address of the computer/device it is on.

Comment: Look like I have to use relative paths. This is not comfortable for me, I use the same texture in different projects, but it is safer

Comment: @user I think you can specify a shared parent directory with relative paths too using generic double dot syntax: `//../textures/foo/bar`